# extract data from javascript using Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, extract

I am a new user to Python, and I have inherited a Python notebook from my predecessor that I want to improve. The purpose of it is to grab product details from a website.

How it works:

- It scrapes the script from a website using beautiful soup:

  ```
  source = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.testwebsite.html').read()
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source)
  job_postings = soup.findAll("script")
  job_postings = [jp for jp in job_postings if not jp.get('type') is None 
                  and ''.join(jp.get('type')) =="text/javascript"
                  and ''.join(jp.get('type')) =="text/javascript"]
  ```

it returns all the script in the webpage:
(1st part of data)

> window.wf=window.wf||{};wf.appData=wf.appData||{};wf.appData.product_data_TEST123=wf.appData.product_data_TEST123||{};wf.appData.product_data_TEST123 = {"sku":"TES123","is_grid_view":false,,"default_img_display":0,"manufacturer_name":"Supplier1","product_name":"product test","part_number":"1234","list_price":1000,"is_price_hidden":false,"base_price":1000,"has_opt":true,"opt_details":[{"option_ids":[],"regular_price":2681.25],"has_free_shipping":false,,"total_qty":1,"display_set_quantity":1,"is_standard_layout":true,"page_type":"ProductPage"};Y_config.app.product_data_TEST123 = {"sku":"TEST123",........ same info here ....};

2 sd part of data:

> \n      wf.extend({"YUI_config":{"app":{"pageAlias":"ProductPage"}},"wf":{"appData":{"pageAlias":"ProductPage",,"mkcName":"AU: FurnitureRoom","productReviews":{"b_show_review_tags":false,"kit_subgroup_price":null,"catalog_currency":"AUD","price_model":null,"colors":"",,"available_after":{"date":"2016-07-28 18:05:16.000000","timezone":"Australia\\/Sydney"},"inventory_info":{"sku":"TEST123",,"latest_inventory_update":"2016-07-29 00:45:06","option_ids":[],"available_quantity":17,"display_quantity":17,","quantity_available_string":" more then 10 in Stock","short_lead_time_id":2,"short_lead_time_string":"Leaves warehouse in 1 to 3 business days"}}};

Then I extract the data I need:

```
   jsonfile =  re.findall(r'wf.appData.product_data_[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4} = (\{.*});YUI_config.app.product_data_',str(job_postings))
```

I have this:

> {"sku":"TEST123","is_grid_view":false,,"default_img_display":0,"manufacturer_name":"Supplier1","product_name":"product test","part_number":"1234","list_price":1000,"is_price_hidden":false,"base_price":1000,"has_opt":true,"opt_details":[{"option_ids":[],"regular_price":2681.25],"has_free_shipping":false,,"total_qty":1,"display_set_quantity":1,"is_standard_layout":true,"page_type":"ProductPage"}

My problem is now: I want to add the "inventory_info" list to my data

I've tried:

```
     jsonfile =  re.findall(r'inventory_info' = (\{.*}),str(job_postings))
```

or

```
    Jsonfile = re.compile('inventory_info' = ({.*?});', re.DOTALL)
```

Neither of those work.

I'm knowledge of Python is very limited so I'm a bit lost now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's good to see new users ask good and proper questions!

Answer (score 0):

You may have already found the answer to your question but here it goes anyways.

For getting `inventory_info`, you could always do a split (assuming job_postings is converted to type `string`), as so:

```
inventory_info = job_postings.split("inventory_info:")[1].split("}")[0] + "}"

job_postings += inventory_info
```